# Delete empty spaces from the beginning and Ending of the textbox c#

Tags: c#, whitespace

How to remove all white spaces from the right and left end of a string, like so:

"hello" return "hello"

"hello   " return "hello"

" hello   " return "hello"

" hello world   " return "hello world"

textbox1.Text    when click button

Comment: textbox1.Text.Trim() is the answer for you ;)

Comment: txtFirstName.Text = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `textbox1.Text` returns a string. As with any string all you need to do is `textbox1.Text.Trim()`, this will remove any leading or trailing whitespace

Comment: the Text property would return a string, you do not need to pass in any parameters into Trim. For instance if your you had `string foo = "   foo "` and you then did `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( foo.Trim().Length )`, you would see the number 3 printed to the debug output.

Comment: also if you're trying to set the value you would do `textbox1.Text = aString.Trim();`

Comment: txtFirstName.Text = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();

this work thanks